# Apache2 error, ubuntu server 20.04

Tags: server, apache2, 20.04, error-handling

Apache2 stoped working, this is the out put of `systemctl status apache2.service`

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-06-28 15:23:33 CDT; 2s ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 3903826 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 28 15:23:33 sturtzsystems apachectl[3903839]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 2604:99c0:8:2ff1:223:24ff:fe08:581f. Set the 'ServerName' >
Jun 28 15:23:33 sturtzsystems apachectl[3903839]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
Jun 28 15:23:33 sturtzsystems apachectl[3903839]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
Jun 28 15:23:33 sturtzsystems apachectl[3903839]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Jun 28 15:23:33 sturtzsystems apachectl[3903839]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Jun 28 15:23:33 sturtzsystems apachectl[3903826]: Action 'start' failed.
Jun 28 15:23:33 sturtzsystems apachectl[3903826]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jun 28 15:23:33 sturtzsystems systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 28 15:23:33 sturtzsystems systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 28 15:23:33 sturtzsystems systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

What is the error and how do I fix it? Thank you and have a good day!
I am running Ubuntu Server 20.04
Error.log is

```
`[Sun Jun 28 14:44:56.911111 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1729] AH00045: child process 3884505 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Jun 28 14:44:56.911179 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1729] AH00045: child process 3875662 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Jun 28 14:44:56.911189 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1729] AH00045: child process 3866395 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Jun 28 14:44:56.911201 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1729] AH00045: child process 3859994 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Jun 28 14:44:56.911211 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1729] AH00045: child process 3875663 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Jun 28 14:44:56.911238 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1729] AH00045: child process 3859991 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Jun 28 14:44:56.911247 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1729] AH00045: child process 3875660 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Jun 28 14:44:56.911256 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1729] AH00045: child process 3877890 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Jun 28 14:44:56.911266 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1729] AH00045: child process 3865589 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Jun 28 14:44:56.911292 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1729] AH00045: child process 3883960 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Jun 28 14:44:56.911302 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1729] AH00045: child process 3851154 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Jun 28 14:44:56.911312 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1729] AH00045: child process 3872390 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Jun 28 14:44:56.911321 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1729] AH00045: child process 3883959 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Jun 28 14:44:56.911330 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1729] AH00045: child process 3855022 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Jun 28 14:44:56.911346 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1729] AH00045: child process 3883943 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Jun 28 14:44:56.911355 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1729] AH00045: child process 3880119 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Jun 28 14:44:56.911364 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1729] AH00045: child process 3877886 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Jun 28 14:44:56.911379 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1729] AH00045: child process 3875664 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Jun 28 14:44:56.911389 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1729] AH00045: child process 3848433 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Jun 28 14:44:56.911398 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1729] AH00045: child process 3865590 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Jun 28 14:44:56.911407 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1729] AH00045: child process 3851155 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Jun 28 14:44:56.911422 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1729] AH00045: child process 3877887 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Jun 28 14:44:56.911431 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1729] AH00045: child process 3877888 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Jun 28 14:44:56.911440 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1729] AH00045: child process 3855020 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Jun 28 14:44:56.911449 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1729] AH00045: child process 3883944 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Jun 28 14:44:56.911457 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1729] AH00045: child process 3851156 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Jun 28 14:44:56.911466 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1729] AH00045: child process 3883958 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Jun 28 14:44:56.911481 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1729] AH00045: child process 3880128 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Jun 28 14:44:56.911490 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1729] AH00045: child process 3865588 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Jun 28 14:44:56.917993 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1729] AH00045: child process 3870727 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Jun 28 14:44:56.918042 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1729] AH00045: child process 3870732 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Jun 28 14:44:56.918053 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1729] AH00045: child process 3877889 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Jun 28 14:44:56.918063 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1729] AH00045: child process 3872389 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Jun 28 14:44:56.918073 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1729] AH00045: child process 3872391 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Jun 28 14:44:56.918082 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1729] AH00045: child process 3848417 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Jun 28 14:44:57.919366 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1729] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

Comment: Check apache log files for more info, usually located `/var/log/apache2/`.

Comment: Maybe some other service/app is running on the port `80` already because You have error `could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80`.

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: Use `sudo netstat -ltnp | grep -w ':80'` (You can check other ports like this). Try killing all apache processes first with `sudo killall -9 apache2` and then try to restart it again.

Comment: I got `sudo: netstat: command not found`

Comment: Install it first `sudo apt install net-tools`.

Comment: ok, I got `tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      3885639/httpd `

Comment: when I run `sudo killall -9 apache2` I get `apache2: no process found`

Comment: Run `sudo killall -9 httpd`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109976/discussion-between-nate-sturtz-and-michal-przybylowicz).